# Azure DevOps - Git fetch failed with exit code 128,

Tags: azure-devops

This question has been asked multiple times on stackoverflow, but the solutions and issues aren't as related to my situation here and since Microsoft doesn't even know the answer, I thought I'd try here.

I have a DevOps project that stores commonly used templates in my environment. We'll call this repo `MainTemplates`. Inside `MainTemplates` contains YAML files that other projects in DevOps extends. In addition, these YAML files also contains extends and sub templates within the same `MainTemplates` repo.

For example. CommonProject contains `DatabaseDeployTemplate.yml` which executes database deploys. At the end of this YAML file, the final step is to call `ChangeLogRequest.yml` which also exists in CommonProject.

I have users that then extends `DatabaseDeployTemplate.yml` to their own separate Projects.

This works, in every project, but one of them. The oddest thing is that the entirety of the template works, expect that last stage of `ChangeLogRequest.yml`. Whereas they use other templates that call `ChangeLogRequest.yml` and those work fine in the BrokenProject. My issue is that BrokenProject only fails `ChangeLogRequest.yml` when calling `DatabaseDeployTemplate.yml`.

I have another project that calls `DatabaseDeployTemplate.yml` and it works without a hiccup. In fact, all of my projects work without a hiccup.

The only output comes from:

```
remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier Common does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
fatal: repository 'https://dev.azure.com/Organization/CommonProject/_git/CommonRepo/' not found
##[warning]Git fetch failed with exit code 128, back off 8.88 seconds before retry.
```

I've tried a lot of things. Build Collection Permissions, Recreating YAML, User permissions, other pipelines and nothing seems to point me in a working direction.

Comment: Git's failure here is not caused by Git itself, but rather by some add-on software (`remote: TF401019: ...` is from that add-on software, which is then telling Git *on the server* to reject the request from your client). No Git expert can help here; this is purely an Azure item.

Comment: @Masterchiefxx17 Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT Yes, it's still a problem. No resolution. Sorry for the late reply. My open ticket with Microsoft still didn't reach a resolution and I was working with them again.

Answer (score 1):

> TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier Common does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.

Since one of the project has this issue and other projects can work fine, you could check the option: `Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines` in **Project Settings(The Pipeline locates) -> Settings** .

The option will limit the pipeline to only access the current project repors. So you need to **Disable** the option: `Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines`.

For example:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is and has always been off on both of my projects. I found this "solution" too, but it does not resolve anything.

Comment: @Masterchiefxx17 Have you tried to disable the option:**Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines** in Project Settings -> Settings.

Comment: Yeah. they're all off.